# QGIS Simplify tool resulting in missing features

Tags: qgis, simplify

I am a very new QGIS user, but have learned much from searching this site for tools that are appropriate for what I am doing.  However, I have reached a roadblock that has stumped me the past several weeks.

I am building a vector contour map using USGS elevation raster data, then using QGIS and GRASS tools to reduce the number of nodes that the resulting vector contours have.

The first map I built turned out very well, using the GRASS v.generalize tool I was able to reduce the file size making it easier to work with.

However, with my second map the vector contour map from the raster image looks great, but when I try to use v.generalize most of the contour lines simply disappear.

I went back and looked at my notes from the first map I built and I believe I am following the exact same process as before.

I even went and used the QGIS simplify tool (to reduce the variable of importing the vector into GRASS) and get the same results, most of the features end up simply disappearing.

I thought perhaps it was an issue with the geometry type, so I added that to my attribute table but all the contour lines appear to be multiline strings, no matter if they ended up simplifying correctly or just disappeared (I was really hoping that would help me clear up what the difference between what stayed and what disappeared was).

If it is of any help, the features that seem to remain are full enclosed contours - this map has a number of contours that trail off of the edge of the raster image and these at least appear to be ones that disappear.  I tried to convert everything to polygons to make these contour lines fully enclosed, but that did not make a difference.  I even tried to then convert them from polygons back into lines but that did not make a difference.

If the answer is not something obvious that my novice eyes just is not seeing, I can work to upload the data and provide a link to it.

[image: Missouri Map Layer Properties][image: Missouri Map Project Properties][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3FY5.jpg) [image: Tennessee Project Properties] [image: Tennessee Project Layer Properties][image: Tennessee map screenshot]

Comment: I forgot to add - I have also used the fix geometry tool, and it does not seem to help either.

Comment: double check the projection/tool units (mixing meters and degrees can lead to what you are describing)

Comment: @MrXsquared - For the map that worked fine, the data started with a USGS 1/9 arc second DEM, EPSG 32715, WGS 84 / UTM Zone 15S (for mid-Missouri).  I did a unit conversion to take it from meters to feet, since I wanted my contour map to have 10 foot intervals.  This was then run through Raster -> Extraction -> Contour.

Comment: @MrXsquared - For the map that did not work, the data started with a USGS 1/3 arc second DEM, EPSG 32616, WGS 84 / UTM Zone 16N (for mid-Tennessee).  I then ran through the same unit conversion from meters to feet for the rater, then did the contour extraction process the same as for the Missouri map.  I am not entirely sure how to give an idea on the number of nodes, is there a certain place I need to go to find that?

Comment: @JGH - Projection information is in the two comments above.

Comment: The map screenshot shows the original contour map, and then you can see the result of the attempt to simplify the map in the yellowish-orange color (the very straight-edged polygons).

Comment: The last 2 screenshots reveals that the coordinates have lat-long values (85W 36N, in Tennessee) but the CRS is declared as UTM, so basically the whole map fits within a few meters around 0;0. There is likely a step where you assigned the UTM projection instead of reprojecting/transforming the data to the UTM projection

Comment: @JGH Thank you, I believe this is the right track, but so far I have not been able to get it to make a difference in the coordinates that it shows.  I followed the steps to transform a layer on https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html  paragraph 7.1.3, but then when I create a new project and add back in the contour map layer it still displays the same coordinate area (85W 36N).  Is there a better tutorial for this out there somewhere?

Comment: you can look at the latest version of the [tutorial](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html). Note that for this to work, the source CRS must be properly defined (if it isn't defined at all, no reprojection will occur, the `save as` would simply assign the selected CRS; if the source CRS is the same as the selected, no reprojection would occur etc)

Comment: @JGH You led me to the fix.  I am not sure what it did not like about what I was doing before.  I would right click on the individual layer, tell it to be in UTM 16N, then go and click on the CRS down in the right-hand corner of the screen and tell the project to be UTM 16N, but still those coordinates still showed in lat-long values as you originally pointed out.

Comment: @JGH Late yesterday I went through and did an export of the raster elevation data again to UTM 16N, saved the layer as a separate file, and opened it.  Then I right-clicked on the layer name, "select CRS," then "set project CRS from layer."  This fixed everything, including causing the coordinates to show in UTM format.  The conversion to contours from the raster and then the "simplify" processing went smoothly.  My only remaining confusion is why changing the layer to the right CRS and changing the project CRS to the right CRS separately did not work.  Regardless I am happy, thanks again.

Comment: _"I would right click on the individual layer, tell it to be in UTM 16N"_ --> this is the wrong step. Doing so means "keep the coordinates numerical values, but now assume they are in UTM instead of lat-long". When you exported the layer in the 2nd attempt (or use a (re)project tool), it means "transform the coordinates numerical values from lat-long to UTM"